# Angular2 Typescript static constructor declaration

Tags: typescript, angular5, static-classes

I lack some practise on static classes and so, I am not able to initialize properly. I have the following class:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

export class Utils {

  static http: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  static uploadMediaFile(file, api: string, model: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file.name, file);
    const uploadReq = new HttpRequest("POST", api, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
    });

    this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
     //blah blah
    });  
  }
}
```

The execution of the above, returns: `"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined"`

Trying to debug, is seems that http is undefined(console.log) so I presume the initialization is not correct.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Why do you use static ,I think you need to create service not class

Comment: What is the utility of `static http: any;` Where do you use that?

Comment: @AmitChigadani that is the case, I am not sure how to initialize the http properly. Creating a service instead, it is more efficient, indeed. Although, it would be interested to find a solution for property initialization in a static class. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `constructor` will invoke if you create new instant of `Utils` class, on the other side `static` (http) is just declared without assign a value that why is Utils.http is undefined.
I believe you may confuse with angular dependency injection, the best case is to create UtilsService an inject http object rather than using static methods.

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  uploadMediaFile(file, api: string, model: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file.name, file);
    const uploadReq = new HttpRequest("POST", api, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
    });

    this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
     //blah blah
    });  
  }
}
```

if you want to use static methods of Utils you have to assign an http object manually before you use it

```
Utils.http = http;
```

after that you can use it;

Answer (score 1):

I see that you want to do a `POST` request with `formData` object. You can use `http.post` instead of `request` method

And no need to use `static http: any`. Also your method need not be a `static`.

```
export class Utils {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  uploadMediaFile(file, api: string, model: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file.name, file);
    const uploadReq = new HttpRequest("POST", api, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
    });

    this.http.post(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
     //blah blah
    });  
  }
}
```